# ext4 - Laptop can't detect sandisk USB

Tags: live-usb, filesystem, ext4

I have recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 onto a USB and noticed I am unable to see it on the "Boot from USB" options. I believe this is due to installing it with the ext4 filesystem. My laptop Aspire 3 a315 doesn't seem to support it.

Question 2: What is expected to be the most common filesystem in 5 years?

So my second question is regarding future proofing. What is expected to be the format that will be most commonly usable for laptops in the next 5 years. Is NTFS a good option? I am not asking in regards to performance I just need it to be usable and what is the most likely format that laptops will still be using.

Comment: ext4 is supported and will be supported for many years to come. The OS supports the file system, not the hardware. Something else is wrong with your LiveUSB. USB flash drives typically are formatted, not with ext4, but with FAT32, because the 'LiveUSB' image is a compressed image which is expanded into memory to create the filesystem used. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163190/why-do-liveusbs-use-squashfs-and-similar-file-systems . How did you make the LiveUSB? What instructions, which URL, did you follow?

Comment: Download Ubuntu's ISO file https://ubuntu.com/download or for a supported 'flavour' with a different Desktop Environment, download from https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours . Next, check for download errors by https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu . Make a LiveUSB following these instructions on another Linux PC https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#0 , on a Windows PC https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows  , or on a Mac https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos.

Comment: We can help with the _can't read LiveUSB_ issue, but question #2 regarding filesystems is subjective and likely to be opinion-based, and therefore as per https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask is off topic here.This is a question-and-answer site, not a forum for open unbounded discussion.

Comment: Can you explain better by installing on USB?  You mean you installed 20.04 on USB or burned a 20.04 ISO to USB.

Comment: I burned 20.04 to a USB then installed it into another USB on my desktop. I am able to see the second USB with Ubuntu installed on it and boot from it on my desktop but my laptop does not detect it. I have no issues with the iso burned image on either device.

Comment: An Installed system, like you have created, will have an ext4 / partition. It may have a small FAT32 EFI partition and a FAT32 or NTFS data partition for sharing data between Windows and Linux computers. Did you use "Something else" when installing Ubuntu? It is critical that the bootloader gets put on the right disk. If you are booting in UEFI mode, your USB needs an EFI partition and the HDD should be unplugged when installing to USB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple potential issues you're running into. I am confident that the filesystem you chose to install to has nothing to do with it not appearing in your UEFI though.

1) Your ESP (the partition your EFI boot entry is installed to) is not present on the USB stick itself (EFI partitions can be placed on any device on the system that supports boot, from USB to SD to SSD/HDD, and more.). If this is the case, you'll need to attempt to reinstall your boot loader/config and make the proper partition adjustments.

2) Your ESP was not properly created (this can mean partition type OR failed bootloader install), and thus your system's UEFI is unable to find the entry to boot.

3) You booted the live image in legacy mode and installed to the USB with these settings, and the hardware is unaware of the OS installed there, or either legacy or UEFI modes are not being displayed under the USB boot options.

--
To clarify on my point about filesystems, it is not the machine's job to support the filesystem, but rather that of the operating system's. Ext4 is the general standard for Linux, but even BTRFS, XFS, and more would be functional options. The hardware is pretty much unaware of these concepts in particular. The only filesystem that matters is the one your boot partition (for EFI), which would need to fall into a few particular standards, being FAT32 ("EFI System Partition" as it's called by the Ubuntu installer) or NTFS (though this is usually only relevant for Windows.)

Comment: How would I go about making sure the ESP is installed on the USB? I did select the USB device as the boot loader.

Comment: I added a EFI partition to the USB and can now boot from it. How big/small does the EFI need to be?